# React button onClick doesn't fire

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I use `create-react-app` command to create my project, it's really strange to me that the button `onClick` doesn't fire. I see this error which I never seen before

`invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's "render" method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded`

Not sure if this error causes button click not firing.
The code is very simple and it's working fine in other projects.

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = React.createClass({
    myClick: function () {
      alert("Hello World!");
    },

    render: function() {
      return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.myClick}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
      ); 
    }
});

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: it's very likely that "you have multiple copies of React loaded". What's your package.json as well as the project look like?

Comment: package.json has these dependencies:                                                                 "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1"
  },

Comment: and where is this component mounted and how?

Comment: `code`ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
    <IndexRoute component={MyComponent}/>
   </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))

Comment: Have you tried removing the node_modules directory and using npm install again?

Comment: Fixed. FYI, it's the problem with node_modules, not react. I use bootstrap in my project, somehow I forgot to npm install bootstrap which causes this error. After running "npm install react-bootstrap --save" and "npm install bootstrap@3 --save", it's working.

Comment: @YinchuHui Could you add that as your answer to close the question? This would help people to not enter and try to answer and also other user that as facing the same problem o/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. FYI, it's the problem with node_modules, not react. I use bootstrap in my project, somehow I forgot to npm install bootstrap, and npm tries to find bootstrap in my root node_modules folder on my computer, this causes this error. After running "npm install react-bootstrap --save" and "npm install bootstrap@3 --save", it's working.